# How do I find the possible combinations of five numbers?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I need to find how many possible combinations I can make using the numbers $3$, $5$, $6$, $7$, and $8$. I need to use all five digits and they must all start with $7$ the rest of the order does not matter.

Could someone offer helpful advice?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: In a combination, the order doesn't matter. Saying that they must start with 7 implies that you are trying to find permutations.